# Numpy filter matrix based on column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix with several different values for each row:

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],[19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27]])
arr2 = np.array([["A"],["B"],["C"]])
```

This produces the following matrices:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]])

array([['A'],
       ['B'],
       ['C']])
```

A represents the first 3 columns, B represents the next 3 columns, and C represents the last 3 columns. So the result I'd like here is:

```
array([[1,2,3],
       [13,14,15],
       [25,26,27]])
```

I was thinking about converting arr2 to a mask array, but I'm not even sure how to do this. If it was a 1darray I could do something like this:

```
arr[0,1,2]
```

but for a 2darray I'm not even sure how to mask like this. I tried this and got errors:

```
arr[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.ascii_uppercase` to index the index in the alphabet. And reshape `arr1` by 3 chunks:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
reshaped = np.reshape(arr1, (len(arr1), -1, 3))
reshaped[np.arange(len(arr1)), np.vectorize(ascii_uppercase.index)(arr2).ravel()]
```

Or just directly map `A` to `0` and so on...

```
reshaped = np.reshape(arr1, (len(arr1), -1, 3))
reshaped[np.arange(len(arr1)), np.vectorize(['A', 'B', 'C'].index)(arr2).ravel()]
```

**Both Output:**

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [25, 26, 27]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gonna have shape of arr1 fixed as shown above `(3,9)` then it can be done with single line of code as below:

```
arr2  = np.array([arr1[0][0:3],arr1[1][3:6],arr1[2][6:9]])
```

The output will be as follows:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [13 14 15]
 [25 26 27]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'advanced indexing' which index the target array by coordinate arrays.

```py
rows = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])
cols = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])

arr1[rows, cols]
>>> array([[ 1,  2,  3],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [25, 26, 27]])
```

and you can make some functions like

```py
def diagonal(arr, step):
    rows = np.array([[x]*step for x in range(step)])
    cols = np.array([[y for y in range(x, x+step)] for x in range(0, step**2, step)])
    return arr[rows, cols]

diagonal(arr1, 3)
>>> array([[ 1,  2,  3],
          [13, 14, 15],
          [25, 26, 27]])
```

reference: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: I know this is from awhile back, but I think this is the closest that could work. Rows seems like it's fine, but cols needs to be more flexible. In reality it may be A, B, A, C, B, ...

Comment: But I think I can probably figure out how to go from an array of ABC and translate them to [0,1,2], [3,4,5], or [6,7,8]. Thanks